# maven equivalent of npms package-lock.json

Tags: maven

**Known: npm**
I am used to `npm` and JavaScript and whenever the dependency tree changes, there is a changed `package-lock.json` generated.  This file includes all dependencies and their transitive dependencies with resolved/fixed versions.

**Unknown: mvn**
Now i have to use Maven and Java.
The question is: What's the maven-equivalent of npms package-lock.json?
I would need this information as to efficiently track which exact versions of (transitive) dependencies are contained in my project/bundle.

Comment: I am not sure if maven is generating file with dependency, but you can check it via command: `mvn dependency:tree`
Some more info you can find here: https://devwithus.com/maven-dependency-tree/

Comment: The versions you are using are defined in your pom file ... you should never use versions range...so use something like `<version>1.2.3</version>`... that makes the usage of a lock file obosolete.

Answer (score -1):

In Maven you usually do not use version ranges - so you'll always have a defined version for a dependency. If you want to change the version of a transitive dependency you can do this using the `dependencyManagement` block (which is similar to the new [npm `overrides`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides)).

If you want a report of the exact dependencies used check out the [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/). You can run a `mvn dependency:tree` to see all dependencies (with relations) including versions.

For more information about Maven dependency mechanism see [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: it seems `mvn dependency:analyze` / `mvn dependency:analyze-report` does list the exact used versions. maybe you can incorporate that into your answer?

Comment: I mentioned dependency:tree (which does the same)

Comment: there is "SNAPSHOT" in `dependency:tree` and "20220207.085336" in `dependency:analyze-report` - so there is a difference...

Comment: @derkoe the use of the maven `dependency` plugin is not the same as having an equivalent of the `package-lock.json` file.
Running that plugging requires downloading all the dependencies first, so it is a computational cost and may require a custom configuration in the `settings.xml`.
My solution is to use the plugin command you mentioned and redirect the output to a "dependencies.log" file which is versioned in the repository along with the source code.

Comment: I was not telling you to run a plugin (this was just to see what is used). If you want to pin your tranbsitive dependencies put them in a dependencyManagement block. Direct dependencies do not need this since you usually never use ranges in Maven.